# HTML String to Open Web Address in New Tab

Tags: html

What string am I missing from this code (below) to enable the web address to open in a new Tab; and where should that string be placed amongst this code?

```
<!-- START ADVERTISER: ######### -->

<a rel="sponsored" href="https://www.abcd.com/cread.php?s=0000000&v=7138&q=298139&r=755009">
    <img src="https://www.abcd.com/cshow.php?s=0000000&v=7138&q=298139&r=755009" border="0">
</a>

<!-- END ADVERTISER: ######## -->
```

Answer (score 0):

**target="_blank" : It will open a new tab with the given URL**

```html
 <a href="https://www.bing.com" target="_blank">Visit</a>
```